# PrestaShop iframe payment module

Tags: prestashop, payment

I'm developing a payment gateway module for prestashop 1.6.x - 1.7.x versions and this module is iFrame. I mean, when a customer chooses this payment method then he's redirected to an iframe page in prestashop (not redirected to another web page). But I must create an order before payment on this page. If I create the order after payment is done in **order-confirmation** page (to this page is automatically redirected to in 5 sec by iframe after the payment is done), it's maybe not the correct way for this method. Maybe the customer has left the iframe page in these 5 secs. So, the order is not created.

When I use the **validateOrder** function for creating an order, it is sending an email to the customer before payment is done. So, I did some changes in this function and it's working fine. But, if this page is refreshed then the order is created over and over again. Also, the validateOrder function is deleting the cart. I duplicate the cart because of this.

I hope everything is ok here. Here are my problems;

- I don't want to show duplicated orders to the customer. Maybe these orders can be updated like id_customer  = 0. But in this case, the customers can not be seen in the BO order table and I don't know if is it legal.
- **validateOrder** function is not compatible with all of these versions. How can I use this for all versions without sending an email? Actually I want to use core function but I guess there is no way.

What is the best practice in this scenario? What is the way I have to follow?

Comment: Post your codes plzz

Comment: I'm using core prestashop codes. Actually there is no need to share codes. All I want is to make the validateOrder function compatible for all versions in one module.